# How to view live search results in a selectable list?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I am totally new in jQuery so hope my question be simple:

I wrote a simple jQuery live search program with PHP and mySQL and it works good.

**My question is:** I want to show search results in a list then select one of the showing results to be written in the text box.

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
$(document).on('keyup', '[name="state"]', function() {
     var partialState = $(this).val();
     $.post("getStates.php",{partialState:partialState}, function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
     });
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <input type = "text" name = "state" autocomplete = "off"/>
   <br>
   <div id = "results"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**My php code:**

```
<?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "")
  or die("Failed to connect to the server: " . mysql_error());

  mysqli_select_db($con, "airlines")
  or die("Failed to connect to the database: " . mysql_error());

  $partialStates = strtoupper($_POST['partialState']);

  if(!$partialStates)
  {
     echo "";
  }
  else
  {
     $states = mysqli_query($con,"select distinct source from flights where source like '%$partialStates%'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($states))
    {
       echo "<div>" . $row['source'] . "</div>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

First look into prepared statement to prevent sql injection at `where source like '%$partialStates%'`.

Then, instead of returning HTML,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($states))
{
echo "<div>" . $row['source'] . "</div>";
}
```

it would be more convenient to work with JSON:

```
$sources = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($states)) {
    $sources[] = $row['source'];
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($sources);
```

To select the first returned state, and update the input box. change

```
$.post("getStates.php",{partialState:partialState}, function(data){
    $("#results").html(data);
});
```

to

```
$.getJSON( "getStates.php", { partialState: partialState }, function( states ) {
    $('input').val(states[0]);
});
```

Comment: My program is good and it is showing results .. my question is how to show results in a selectable list then select one of the showing result to be written in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  //PHP Code
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root")
  or die("Failed to connect to the server: " . mysql_error());

  mysqli_select_db($con, "dedecms")
  or die("Failed to connect to the database: " . mysql_error());

  $partialStates = strtoupper($_GET['partialState']);

  if(!$partialStates)
  {
  echo "###";
  }
else
{
 $states = mysqli_query($con,"select typename  from dede_arctype where typename like '%$partialStates%'") or die(mysql_error());
  $sources = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($states)) {
  $sources[] = $row['typename'];
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($sources);
}
?>
HTML Code:
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$(document).on('mouseout', '[name="state"]', function(){
    var html;
         var partialState = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("getStates.php",
    {
        partialState: partialState
    }, function(states)
    {
        $('input').val(states[0]);
        $.each(states, function(i, value)
        {
            html += value;
            $("#results").html(html);
        });
    });

});
```

});

```
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="state" autocomplete="off" />
    <br>
    <div id="results"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How does this solve the question? There is a lot of code but 0 javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!